# bash: problem with finding Weekday from Date - error "multiple output formats specified"

Tags: bash, date, datetime

I'm testing some functions in bash date utility and while subtraction from a certain datetime value works fine, I am unable to check if certain date is a Monday or not:

```
#!/bin/bash


export TZ=UTC
ZIPPED="$1"

gunzip "$ZIPPED"

UNZIPPED=${ZIPPED%.*}

TRDAY_raw=${UNZIPPED%%.*} # 20200427
test=$(date -Is -d "$TRDAY_raw -3 day")
echo "MINUS 3 DAYS ---> $test"

if [[ $(date -Is -d "${TRDAY_raw}" +%u) -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "$TRDAY_raw is Monday"
fi

gzip $UNZIPPED
```

I run the above code like this:

```
bash /test/dates/wday.sh 20200427.global.csv.gz
```

And the output is this:

```
MINUS 3 DAYS ---> 2020-04-24T00:00:00+0000
date: multiple output formats specified
```

How could I find a weekday in this situation?

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Remove the `-Is` arg from `$(date -Is -d "${TRDAY_raw}" +%u) -eq 1` so that it is just `$(date -d "${TRDAY_raw}" +%u) -eq 1`

Comment: @LeadingEdger - that would make a nice answer combined with the man-page explanation of the `-I[FMT]` options and how `-I` and `+"..."` are mutually exclusive.